# How to override user.profile type?

Tags: meteor, typescript

In [meteor-typescript's definition file](https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-libs/blob/master/definitions/meteor.d.ts#L49), the `user.profile` object is typed as `any`.

What's the Typescript way to extend the user object and change the profile type?

I tried

```
interface IMyUserProfile {
  foo: boolean;
}

namespace Meteor {
  export interface User: {
    profile: IMyUserProfile
  }
}
```

But TS just says "duplicate identifier".

I know I could change it in the definitions file directly but for obvious reasons I'd prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript supports [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) but that would have worked if you'd add a property that isn't already in place, for example:

```
namespace Meteor {
    export interface User {
        newPropertry: any;
    }
}
```

But since the `User` interface already has `profile` the compiler complains about it.

What you can do is:

```
namespace Meteor {
    export interface MyUser extends User {
        profile: IMyUserProfile;
    }
}
```

And then just cast the user instance you have to `Meteor.MyUser`.
You can of course remove that from the `Meteor` namespace:

```
export interface MyUser extends Meteor.User {
    profile: IMyUserProfile;
}
```

Comment: Right. That's a bit of a shame though, I'd really like to be able to override when merging declarations.

Comment: Well, you can override methods (with different signatures of course), and add variables which weren't declared, that should answer most of the scenarios. In the other cases you'll need to workaround it.